# Python AES-CBC implementation using AES-ECB

Tags: python, python-3.x, programming-challenge, reinventing-the-wheel, cryptography

I am looking for ways to make this code more "pythonic" and any issues with my implementation. This was designed to solve [Crytopal's Challenge 10](https://cryptopals.com/sets/2/challenges/10). This challenge requires recreating the AES-CBC cipher using a library-provided AES-ECB function. [PKCS7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS#5_and_PKCS#7) padding is also used to align bytes to block boundaries.

```
from Cryptodome.Cipher import AES

def xor(in1, in2):
    ret = []
    for i in range(0, max(len(in1), len(in2))):
        ret.append(in1[i % len(in1)] ^ in2[i % len(in2)])
    return bytes(ret)

def decrypt_aes_ecb(data, key):
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_ECB)
    return cipher.decrypt(data)    

def encrypt_aes_ecb(data, key):
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_ECB)
    return cipher.encrypt(data)  

def pkcs7(val, block_size=16):
    remaining = block_size - len(val) % block_size
        if remaining == block_size:
            remaining = 16
    ret = val + chr(remaining).encode() * remaining

    return ret

def unpkcs7(val, block_size=16):
    pad_amount = val[-1]
    if pad_amount == 0:
        raise Exception
    for i in range(len(val) - 1, len(val) - (pad_amount + 1), -1):
        if val[i] != pad_amount:
            raise Exception
    return val[:-pad_amount]

def decrypt_aes_cbc(data, key, iv = b'\x00' * 16, pad=True):
    prev_chunk = iv

    decrypted = []

    for i in range(0, len(data), 16):
        chunk = data[i : i + 16]
        decrypted += xor(decrypt_aes_ecb(chunk, key), prev_chunk)
        prev_chunk = chunk

    if pad:
        return unpkcs7(bytes(decrypted))
    return bytes(decrypted)

def encrypt_aes_cbc(data, key, iv = b'\x00' * 16, pad=True):
    if pad:
        padded = pkcs7(data)
    else:
        padded = data

    prev_chunk = iv

    encrypted = []

    for i in range(0, len(padded), 16):
        chunk = padded[i : i + 16]
        encrypted_block = encrypt_aes_ecb(xor(chunk, prev_chunk), key)
        encrypted += encrypted_block
        prev_chunk = encrypted_block

    return bytes(encrypted)
```

Comment: Links can rot. [Please include a description of the challenge here in your question.](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1993)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Try to follow PEP8. Just a few little things like when assigning defaults to arguments don't put spaces around the `=`; two spaces between functions and imports; `[i : i + 16]` -> `[i: i + 16]`. Very minor stuff but adds up over a larger piece of code.
- Avoid assigning variables to small bits of logic if they're only going to be used once. e.g.:

  ```
  ret = val + chr(remaining).encode() * remaining
  return ret
  ```

  Could become:

  ```
  return val + chr(remaining).encode() * remaining
  ```
- Your names could be improved for clarity; avoid using vague names like key, var, data, etc.
- I like ternary operators so I'd change `encrypt_aes_cbc()` to:

  ```
  padded = pkcs7(data) if pad else data
  ```

  You can do something similar in `decrypt_aes_cbc()` with your returns.
- In fact, I'd extract the second part of the function to a generator and call it in `encrpyt_aes_cbc()`. By which I mean:

  ```
  def gen_encrypted(key, iv):
      """Maybe give this function a better name!"""

      for i in range(0, len(padded), 16): 
          ...
      yield encrypted
  ```

  Then change the second half of `encrypt_aes_cbc()` to call that generator. This nicely compartmentalises your code, removes the need for the `encrypted` list and should be faster. I can explain this more thoroughly if you're confused about `yield`.
- Your argument `block_size=16` in `unpkcs7` is not used.
- Your indentation is off in `pkcs7`.
- Try to be specific when raising exceptions. What error exactly are you catching? Exceptions also takes a string argument so you can explain the problem. e.g.:

  ```
  raise IndexError('This is not a valid position in some_list')
  ```

Comment: Especially the comment on using specific exceptions and error messages is enormously important! Nothing is more annoying than having to read error messages (if any) that tell you nothing apart from "It's broken!"

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Hobo's good answer, you can simplify the `xor` function

> ```
> def xor(in1, in2):
>     ret = []
>     for i in range(0, max(len(in1), len(in2))):
>         ret.append(in1[i % len(in1)] ^ in2[i % len(in2)])
>     return bytes(ret)
> ```

You don't need the `0` in the range's first element because it will automatically start at `0`, secondly `bytes` will accept any iterable so you can feed it a comprehension

```
def xor(in1, in2):
    return bytes(in1[i % len(in1)] ^ in2[i % len(in2)] for i in range(max(len(in1), len(in2)))
```

You could also use `cycle` from the `itertools` module in combination with `zip`

```
from itertools import cycle

def xor2(in1, in2):
    value, repeater = (in1, in2) if len(in1) > len(in2) else (in2, in1)
    return bytes(v ^ r for v, r in zip(value, cycle(repeater)))
```